# Where to find any example loading json model in scenejs?

Tags: json, 3d, scenejs

I've a JSON model with vertices, uvs, indices etc which is exported using Blender. It works fine with other frameworks. I also want to try it using ScenejS. But couldn't find decent example implementing JSON model using SceneJS. It would be helpful if someone redirect me to place where I can study and work on SceneJS using JSON model. I really wonder, is there any demo available using JSON model in SceneJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examples are on the website, as well as bundled with the sourcecode at github (which you'll need to build).

http://scenejs.org/dist/v2.0.0/extr/examples/index.html

This example shows how to define geometry using the JSON API:

http://scenejs.org/dist/v2.0.0/extr/examples/custom-geometry/index.html

Documentation on geometry definition on the wiki:

https://github.com/xeolabs/scenejs/wiki/geometry

Comment: Thanks for the links. how could I calculate FPS for the above example (custom geometry)? Any boiler plate code help please.

Comment: I was asking for the example which implemented JSON model, I mean accessing it through uri. I can see examples which you gave on your site. how could I calculate FPS for the above example (custom geometry)? Any boiler plate code help please.

WHAT I really meant is: 
var jsonXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
jsonXhr.open('GET', url, true);

this approach works?

Comment: SceneJS allows you to implement your own plugins for loading from URLs : https://github.com/xeolabs/scenejs/wiki/GeoLoader-Service